# A difficulty in understanding the proof of theorem 1.14 in Hungerford.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, proof-explanation

The theorem and part of it is proof is given in the following 2 pictures:

[image]
[image]

But I could not understand why the injections, projections, $f^{-1}\iota_{i}$ and $\pi_{i}f$ satisfy (i)-(iii). could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these are just straightforward computation from the definitions. First in the case $A = A_1\oplus \dots\oplus A_n$.

(i): for all $a\in A_1$, we have $\pi_1(\iota_1(a)) = \pi_1((a,0,\dots,0)) = a$. Similarly for all $1\leq i\leq n$.

(ii): for all $a\in A_1$ and all $j\neq 1$, we have $\pi_j(\iota_1(a)) = \pi_j((a,0,\dots,0)) = 0$. Similarly for all $1\leq i\leq n$ and $j\neq i$.

(iii): for all $a = (a_1,\dots,a_n)\in A$, we have $\iota_i(\pi_i(a)) = \iota_i(a_i) = (0,\dots,a_i,\dots,0)$. So $(\iota_1\pi_1 + \dots + \iota_n\pi_n)(a) = (a_1,0\dots,0) + \dots + (0,\dots,0,a_n) = (a_1,\dots,a_n) = a$.

Now in the case $f\colon A \cong A_1\oplus \dots\oplus A_n$, we use the results of (i) through (iii) above.

(i): $(\pi_if)(f^{-1}\iota_i) = \pi_i \iota_i = 1_{A_i}$.

(ii): $(\pi_jf)(f^{-1}\iota_i) = \pi_j\iota_i = 0$.

(iii): $(f^{-1}\iota_1)(\pi_1f)+ \dots + (f^{-1}\iota_n)(\pi_nf) = f^{-1}(\iota_1\pi_1+\dots+\iota_n\pi_n)f = f^{-1}1_{A_1\oplus\dots\oplus A_n} f = f^{-1}f = 1_A$.

Comment: But the theorem said in (i) that $\pi_{i}i_{i} = 1_{A_{i}} $ and you get in your answer a not 1_{A_{i}, what is the relation?

Comment: $a$ is an element of $A_i$, and we get it back. That's what the identity function $1_{A_i}$ does.

Comment: Note that $\pi_i \iota_i$ is a function $A_i\to A_i$, not an element. $1_{A_i}$ is the identity function, not some unit element (modules don't even have units). To show $\pi_i \iota_i = 1_{A_i}$ is to show that $\pi_i(\iota_i(a)) = 1_{A_i}(a)= a$ for all $a$.

Comment: why the author divide the first implication into 2 cases (1)when $A = A_{1} \oplus ....\oplus A_{n}$ ..... and when (2)$A \cong    A_{1} \oplus ....\oplus A_{n}$ ?

Comment: some modules have units they are called unitary modules .....right?

Comment: or you mean by units that every element has a multiplicative identity?

Comment: I just meant that $1_{A_i}$ must denote the identity function here, not some element of $A_i$, because in a general module $A$ there is no element called $1_A$. Modules don't have multiplicative identities - they don't even have multiplication! Modules equipped with a multiplication operation are called algebras, and algebras can have multiplicative identity elements.

Comment: A unitary module is one in which the identity element of the ring acts as the identity on the module. There is still no element called $1$ in the module.

Comment: The author divides the proof into two cases to make it easier to read. It's clearer in case of equality, since you don't have to mess around with $f$ and $f^{-1}$, and then the case of isomorphism follows easily from the case of equality, as in my answer.